# Route 2 LAN — Device Without Gateway Isn't Reachable On Different LAN

Tags: router, routing

[image: Network Diagram]

Hi peeps, I am routing 2 LAN like the above drawing with the intention of making all devices talk to each other regardless of which LAN they're in. But I am having issue **pinging/access AV Device from Computer A**.

Some info:

1. I have no control of the switch and computer within the red zone. Can only make suggestion/amendment to it through another person.
2. I can ping/access Computer A from Computer B.
3. I can ping/access AV Device from Computer B.
4. I can ping/access Computer B from Computer A.
5. I can't ping/access AV Device from Computer A.
6. AV Device has no option for setting Gateway, only IP Address and Subnet.
7. I have added static route in the router to point to the AV Device but I still couldn't ping/access AV Device from Computer B.

I am trying to make AV Device reachable by Computer A. Possible? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

@Eddy, What type of Device is the 'A/V Device'?  This may help us understand your issue, and allow us to recommend a solution.  You've really already identified the issue, "AV Device has no option for setting Gateway, only IP Address...".  In a routed WAN/LAN you will need the Default Gateway set, or a "Policy Based Route" in your Router/Firewall, in order to successfully route the return traffic (Syn-Ack) from 'A/V Device' to 'Computer A'.  If you can load DD-WRT (Open-Source) Firmware on your Asus Router, which I believe your model supports, then you could create a Policy Based Route...Which 'may' appropriately route the traffic between 'Computer A' and the 'A/V Device'.  The following URL/Link will take you to the section of the DD-WRT Support Site and demonstrate Policy Based Routing.  [DDWRT Policy-Based Routing](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Policy_Based_Routing).  Hope this Helps!

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you! It's a projector. Network setting is on page 65/140. I would like to see if I can make it work with existing stock firmware first before I load 3rd party firmware.

Comment: @Eddy, I tried finding a Projector that is Network capable, but doesn't have settings for a Default Gateway, and unfortunately came up empty.  Do you mind sharing the Manufacturer/Model?  Without the Default Gateway you will be limited to accessing the device on the 'Local LAN/Subnet' that the Projector is directly connected to (Unless you are able to apply the Policy Routing I referred to earlier, and even this may not work perfectly).  I'm Sorry I couldn't Help More, but if you're able to provide the Projector Details we may be able to help more! :)

Comment: Sorry, Andrew, I intended to put the link to the projector manual in my previous comment but it didn't showed up. Here's the link again: https://goo.gl/dwnGYH (page 65 of 140).

Comment: No Worries Eddy.. ;)  I thought that may be the case.  So I have reviewed the Manual, and you're absolutely right there isn't any setting that allows you to 'Manually' define a Default Gateway.  However, I want to clarify something before we move on...  Within the "Network Settings" configuration page, are you using DHCP or Manually setting the IP Address?  The reason I ask is that DHCP will, by default, provide the requesting system with the following (at minimum):  IP Address, Subnet Mask and Default gateway.  If you choose DHCP, I'm curious to see if you can reach the Projector?

Comment: Thanks Andrew! It was using static IP. I'll check if the DHCP can assign the default gateway automatically to the projector.

Answer (score 0):

@Eddy, I'm not sure why I didn't think of this last night, but Your Best Option for successfully routing the Projector 'Device A' may actually be a Proxy-Arp entry.  As we've covered, without the Default Gateway being set in the Projector you cannot (without assistance) route packets beyond the Local Subnet.  The Default Gateway, combined with either 'Directly Connected', 'Static', or 'Dynamic' routes will provide Layer 3 (L3) traffic routing via the Router/Firewall/Gateway.  Since we don't have this option with your Projector, we could use Proxy-Arp entries to effectively provide Layer 2 (L2) path "routing".  Proxy-Arp will basically allow us Statically Create an 'ARP'(Address Resolution Protocol) entry that will help us "Route" the Remote IP Address.  The ASUS Router/Firewall will answer the ARP request, and since the Projector has no defined L3 gateway to send traffic to it will send it to the ASUS Router which is acting as the "Proxy", because 'Computer A' is "Outside or Off-Network" of the Local Subnet/LAN.  Let me know if this works, otherwise you will likely have to load the DD-WRT or another Open-Source Full-Featured firmware on your router to get the features you need to connect to the Projector.

Comment: Thanks again Andrew! Where does this proxy-arp located and needs to be set? Existing switch or router?